# Model is auto-checking for active = 1 why? laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have in database 3 rows with languages  english, italian, polish. When i call  model  $languages = Language::all();  and use dd($languages) it shows 3 languages stored in variable. When i foreach  it in view it shows **one ACTIVE** language. It looks like some sort of data binding but i am not sure where to disable it.

I've noticed that if i change variable name to $langs = Languages::all() and use in foreach($langs as $language)  it displays all languages. I would like to understand how it works.

model Language.php

```
namespace App\SupremeShop\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Language extends Model
{
    protected $table="supremeshop_langs";
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

controller:

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $languages = Language::all();

    return View('themes.supremeBackend.pages.language.index')
        ->with('languages', $languages);
}
}
```

view:

```
@foreach ( $languages as $language )
{{ $language->name }}
@endforeach
```

displays:

```
english
```

Should show 3 differents languages from database.

Comment: If you remove `$languages = Language::all();` and just `dd($languages);` what do you get?

Comment: As @mozammil suggest `dd($languages);` may be the other languages don't have names `{{ $language->name }}`

Comment: Have you inherited this website, or did you build it yourself?

Comment: It shows:  Undefined variable: languages   Screens from error and db https://ibb.co/s2SDRYk
https://ibb.co/L9V8d7t

Comment: @MarekKaliszuk, don't delete the languages assignment, just add the dd underneath.

Comment: dd will show 3 langs: https://ibb.co/tJfqhHR  In view will be 1  where column has  active=1

Comment: Also if i use $languages = Language::all();  and rename column name from 'active' to for example 'activeee'  - it will show error that column 'active' don't exist. But there is nowhere code for checking that.. App is builded from clean laravel 5.7 - nothing added. Well i could live with variable $langs instead $languages but curiosity wins for now :/

Comment: To array: https://ibb.co/DzhwmVZ

Comment: Could you share the code from bootstrap/app.php ?

Comment: If you remove the `->with('languages', $languages);` and just `dd($languages)` in the view? Does it show anything?

Comment: ^^ Either $languages is being mutated in the view somewhere, or you have something injecting a different $languages variable globally (like View::share)

Comment: Look into [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers). `$languages` must be injected to your view from somewhere. A quick search and you would find it.

Comment: Guys u are right!  Thanks!   I had on frontend languages shared.  ( $view->with('languages', \App\SupremeShop\Models\Language::where('active',1)->get());) After removing that langs are working.